# Entitytype object to simple_array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello i have this EntityType

```
 ->add('emotions', EntityType::class, array('class' =>   'MovieBundle:Emotion', 'choice_label'=>'emotion', 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true))
```

I try to persist it to databse  with property Emotions

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="emotions", type="array")
 * 
 */
private $emotions;
```

So in db i get this:

O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:1:{i:0;O:26:"MovieBundle\Entity\Emotion":2:{s:30:"MovieBundle\Entity\Emotionid";i:1;s:35:"MovieBundle\Entity\Emotionemotion";s:6:"cheery";}}}

It is very ugly. So try to make it simple and change it into this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="emotions", type="simple_array")
 * 
 */
private $emotions;
```

unfortunately i get an error
Warning: implode() Invalid arguments passed.
Despite i define an arrayCollection in construct, i still have this error

Comment: Why not use a ManyToMany relationship? You cant use a simple array because you are trying to store an array of Objects. You either have to use just array and deal with how it looks in the DB or setup a many to many relationship(My preferred suggestion)

Comment: @Chausser Yeah, ManytoMany seemed to be pretty obvious idea. i did not figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Did you need help with the ManyToMany setup? or were you meaning that you were unable to figure out how to store it as a simple array?

Comment: @Chausser is it possible instead use ManyToMany handle that json result above? When I try to do it Symfony gives me: "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"

Comment: @Giovani if you want to start a new question with your setup and error, i would be happy to take a look at it.